# adding an order to a new account

Tags: module, magento-1, user

I am trying to create a new account for guest checkouts and assign the order to that account i have an observer for `sales_order_place_after` and creates an account through this code, it works and the account is created but the order is not saved to the account am i missing something? (Magento 1.8.1.0)

```
    $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();     
    $autoregister_array["customerSaved"] = false;
    $email = $order->getCustomerEmail();
    $firstname  = $order->getCustomerFirstname();
    $lastname  = $order->getCustomerLastname();
    $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer');
    $customer->setWebsiteId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getWebsiteId())->loadByEmail($email);
    if (!$customer->getId()) {
        $randomPassword = $customer->generatePassword(12);
        $customer->setId(null)
            ->setSkipConfirmationIfEmail($email)
            ->setFirstname($firstname)
            ->setLastname($lastname)
            ->setEmail($email)
            ->setPassword($randomPassword)
            ->setConfirmation($randomPassword)
            ->setPasswordConfirmation($randomPassword);
        $customer->save();
        Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->loginById($customer->getId());
        $order->setCustomerId($customer->getId());
        $order->setCustomerIsGuest(0);
        $order->save();
    }
```

Comment: What is the `$customer->getId()` return value after you save customer ?

Comment: the customers id in the customer grid on the backend, I logged that and it matches, also the login part works fine.

Comment: Great. `sales_order_place_after`  occurs after payment, have you tried subscription to `sales_order_place_before` ?

Comment: yes i tried `sales_order_place_before ` it did not work

Comment: Related info: http://inchoo.net/magento/programmatically-create-order-in-magento/ They use the admin order creation model instead of the user one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK so i needed to listen for a later event `sales_order_save_commit_after`
and then i was able to add it to the order with this code

```
    $_order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($order->getId());
    if ($_order->getCustomerIsGuest()==true){
        $_order->setCustomerId($customer->getId());
        $_order->setCustomerIsGuest(0);
        $_order->setCustomerGroupId(1);
        $_order->save();    
    }
```